# How can I copy one specific commit to another branch?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches :

- branchA
- branchB

I checkout `branchB`, and fix a small thing while I am on that branch.

```
commit f2c88cad3d7648cad9c12e724d09db0952abec63
Author: Name <email>
Date:   Fri Mar 18 09:10:22 2016 -0400

    Fix small bug on dashboard
```

Then, I do `git push origin branchB`, but I should have done `git push origin branchA branchB`.

Now, in branchB I have

```
commit f2c88cad3d7648cad9c12e724d09db0952abec63
```

but I don't have it on branchA.

How do I copy that one commit `f2c88ca` into my branchA as well ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use git cherry-pick command to copy commit to another branch. In your case, once you checkout branchA then do

```
git cherry-pick f2c88ca
```

Comment: Excellent! Just to clarify 'f2c88ca' is the actual commit name.

Comment: When Git works , it creates magic..   if it doesn't  it creates panic..